# Task assignment problem with capabilities and time restrictions

Tags: algorithms, assignment-problem, multi-tasking

I have the following optimalization problem. I use the notations below because maybe it would be easier to understand that way, but I'm not good at conventions – I'm not sure if I'm using it all the right way – so feel free to correct me on this.

We have multiple tasks, $T_1,…, T_n$. Each of them has exactly one type (or is of a specific **k**ind), $K_1,…K_s$ (notice that number of types is independent from the number of tasks). Each of them also has its start and end time, $S_k$ and $S'_k$.

We also have multiple workers, $W_1,…W_r$. Each of them is available for a limited number of time and finishes its work on $E_k$ (like **e**xpiration). Every worker is capable of performing specific types of tasks, so $C(W_k) = \{K_{a_1}, …, K_{a_n} \}$ (**C** from **c**apabilities). Each worker can only perform one task at a time, but we may have multiple workers with the same capabilities.

Now, our task is not to plan the whole flow – new workers may come and we don't know anything about this. The thing is, a worker ($W_a$) comes to us at a specific time and asks for a task ($T$) to perform. We know the worker's "expiration date" ($E$), so we know we can't give him task where $S'_k > E_a$ (he won't be able to finish it). We have to give him a specific task, preferably the one that starts soon, but that's not a strong constraint. We have to maximize the number of tasks performed, knowing all the workers that we now have and knowing that we'll have them until they expire.

An example, maybe?

Let's say we have 4 kinds of tasks, $K_1, K_2, K_3, K_4$. We have three workers with the following capabilities:

$C(W_1) = \{K_1, K_2, K_4\}$

$C(W_2) = \{K_1, K_2\}$

$C(W_3) = \{K_1, K_2, K_3\}$

And we have our tasks, let's say four of them. Here are the types with start and end times:

$T_1$ (type $K_1$) spans from $0$ to $20$

$T_2$ (type $K_2$) spans from $10$ to $40$

$T_3$ (type $K_3$) spans from $15$ to $50$

$T_4$ (type $K_4$) spans from $25$ to $50$

So it looks like this:

```
         |------T3------|
      |-----T2----|
|----T1----| |----T4----|
```

So let's say we're at the time $0$ – the beginning of my beautiful illustration – and the worker $W_3$ comes to us. We could give him task $T_1$ – he's capable of doing it – but then nobody could do the task $T_3$, since he's the only one for that job. So we tell him to wait and then do $T_3$.

$W_1$ would do $T_1$ and $T_4$. $W_2$ would be left with $T_2$.

That was a rather simple example, but I hope you get the idea.

I have read numerous articles about different types of task assignment problems, but I didn't find anything similar (or specific) enough.

Comment: In your example, you have not given the Expiration date of the workers? And,  to decide the optimal scheduling, we also need the arriving time of the workers, right? or Are you assuming that workers are available all the time?

Comment: You are correct, the example doesn't cover expiration time, but it's a pretty simple constraint. And the arrival time – yes, you are right that would be necessary to generalize my problem a little more, but originally the assumption was that if a worker is on the list, they would be available for the whole period from now (time of evaluation) to their expiration date.

Comment: Well, I've now realized that the arrival time should always be included — because this whole planning would take place every time some new worker arrives (to keep it optimal), it is possible that we assign some task to a worker now, at time 0, and later, at time 15, we would have absolutely no data on when this worker will end that task. It's a very obvious mistake and yet I didn't catch that. Thank you, I will update this question later today.